# How to count unique ID after groupBy in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the following code to agregate students per year. The purpose is to know the total number of student for each year.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
gr = Df2.groupby(['Year'])
df_grouped = 
gr.agg(fn.count(col('Student_ID')).alias('total_student_by_year'))
```

The problem that I discovered that so many ID's are repeated, so the result is wrong and huge.

I want to agregate the students by year, count the total number of student by year and avoid the repetition of ID's.

Comment: I called the data from Hive table

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Use **countDistinct** function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct
x = [("2001","id1"),("2002","id1"),("2002","id1"),("2001","id1"),("2001","id2"),("2001","id2"),("2002","id2")]
y = spark.createDataFrame(x,["year","id"])

gr = y.groupBy("year").agg(countDistinct("id"))
gr.show()
```

output

```
+----+------------------+
|year|count(DISTINCT id)|
+----+------------------+
|2002|                 2|
|2001|                 2|
+----+------------------+
```

Comment: For completeness sake, you can also use `.alias()` to rename the column.

Comment: Note that countDistinct does not count Null as a distinct value!

Comment: Base on which version ?

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

`gr.groupBy("year", "id").count().groupBy("year").count()`

This query will return the unique students per year.

Answer (score 1):

`countDistinct()` and multiple aggr both are not supported in streaming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with an older Spark version and don't have the `countDistinct` function, you can replicate it using the combination of `size` and `collect_set` functions like so:

```
gr = gr.groupBy("year").agg(fn.size(fn.collect_set("id")).alias("distinct_count"))
```

In case you have to count distinct over multiple columns, simply concatenate the columns into a new one using `concat` and perform the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

By using Spark/PySpark SQL

```
y.createOrReplaceTempView("STUDENT")
    
spark.sql("SELECT year, count(DISTINCT id) as count" + \
"FROM STUDENT group by year").show()
```